# How implement my personalized @secured annotation

Tags: java, security, proxy, annotations

I'm trying to implement my @secured annotation similar to Spring's, but generalized to any project and I'm having problems. 
I looked at a lot of documentation but my internet is really restringed and need an answer. My idea is that the code to use it is like this:

```
public class a {
  @secured (access> 3)
  private void a() {}
}
```

The controller:

```
public class SecuredProvider {
private void check () {
if (accessLevesOfMethod> registerUser.getAccesLevel ()) {
// execute method
} else {
throw new exception ();
}
}
```

in the main

```
new A (). a ();
```

And if the logged user have an access level < 3 throws an exception, any other case they method is executed normally.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with AOP, using Dependency injection with google's GUICE an intercepting every method with @Secure